# Android App crashing due to classcastexception when using sliding menu library

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am getting this error when my app crashes due to [Sliding Menu Library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

```
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1826)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at  android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1337)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1620)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at  android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.onLayout(CustomViewAbove.java:476)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1983)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can anyone help me in this issue. i tried to download fresh copy of library and use, but even then it is not solved. im compiling all my project dependent projects and app with android 5.0

Comment: Please post your java code here!

Comment: you have to post your source code.

Answer (score 1):

Check/Organise your imports(**ctrl** + **shift** + **o**, in Eclipse) in `CustomViewAbove.java` and ensure that if `LayoutParams` have been used anywhere, they are from the package of `android.widget.AbsListView`.

Basically that is what your error is telling you:

```
12-31 14:02:54.319: E/AndroidRuntime(4121): java.lang.ClassCastException:   
android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

If `LayoutParams` are being used at multiple places(other than line no. 476), then need to import both packages accordingly.